# Update hostname by connecting to Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, mac-address, hostname

SCENARIO:

I'm looking to have a Linux box on startup connect to a Ruby on Rails website that has list of hostnames added to a Model. The Linux box updates it's own hostname from the next available hostname record in the list AND logs it's MAC address and IP Address in the rails site.  Tough right?

**Ruby on Rails Application**

Host.rb (model) ip_address:string, mac_address:string, hostname:string, available:boolean

Tough part:

I'm trying to figure out how to have the Linux box connect the the RoRs site to see all my Host records, which will list all the hostnames. Ie:

```
id:1 hostname: "hostname-1", ip_address: nil, mac_address: nil, available: true
id:2 hostname: "hostname-2", ip_address: nil, mac_address: nil, available: true
id:3 hostname: "hostname-3", ip_address: nil, mac_address: nil, available: true
```

.. then look at the next available hostname and updates itself to that hostname while logging the mac_address and ip_address to that record.

After the Linux box "downloads" the hostname the record would look like:

```
id:1 hostname: "hostname-1", ip_address: "192.168.1.10", mac_address: "00:13:EF:35:GH:00":, available: false
id:2 hostname: "hostname-2", ip_address: nil, mac_address: nil, available: true
id:3 hostname: "hostname-3", ip_address: nil, mac_address: nil, available: true
```

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

I placed a new file in /etc/init.d/selfconfig

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/selfconfig

USER=root
HOME=/root

export USER HOME

# download remote /zip file with hostname inside
/usr/bin/wget -o /home/admin/selfconfig.zip http://examplewebsite.com/selfconfig.zip
# unzip the .zip file
/usr/bin/unzip -o /home/admin/selfconfig.zip /home/admin
# copy the hostname file to the primary hostname location
cp /home/admin/hostname /etc/hostname

exit 0
```

This works exactly how I want it to updating the hostname after reboot, but the hostname file is inside a static .zip file. I need to be able to update the .zip file dynamically or somehow have the Linux box connect to the site itself and pull a json list or something. This is where I'm stuck.

REASONING:

I'm going to be setting up about 150 of these machines and this would eliminate SO much hassle.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a controller on the Rails app having a method:

```
def hostname
  host = Host.where(available: true).order(:id).first
  if host.present?
    render :text => host.hostname
  else
    render :text => 'No hostname available'
  end
end
```

Let's say you have configured the route to access this as `http://examplewebsite.com/hostname`. You can get the hostname from the init shell script this way:

`lwp-request http://examplewebsite.com/hostname > /etc/hostname`

Of course, you should check for hostname depletion by checking the return value of lwp-request. You can use curl or another http client to request the necessary info but I think this is out of scope of the question.

Sending the MAC and IP address can be done by appending them as GET query parameters like this:

`lwp-request http://examplewebsite.com/hostname?mac=$mac&ip=$ip > /etc/hostname`

provided you have gathered the MAC and IP addresses in corresponding variables.

Then, on the rails side, you can log them like this:

```
def hostname
  host = Host.where(available: true).order(:id).first
  if host.present?
    host.update_attributes({
      ip_address: params[:ip],
      mac_address: params[:mac] 
    })
    render :text => host.hostname
  else
    render :text => 'No hostname available'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. I'm going to give this a go and see what happens. I will accept as answer if it works!

Comment: One quick question… how is the controller detecting that the client is accessing it, and when would it be making the change from available:true, to available:false? (I guess that's two questions)

Comment: Ah, you can authenticate using a secret token, for example, so only your client will be able to access it - just pass the token as another get parameter and check it on the rails side.

Comment: Regarding the available, yes, I forgot about it, just set it along with ip_address and mac_address as another line: `available: false`

Comment: Hello again, everything is looking very promising! When putting the "lwp-request" line in my /etc/init.d/selfconfig file, I'm getting a `/usr/bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error.  Any ideas? I know this is perl.. but I'm not sure what to change.

Comment: answered my previous question at this post incase anyone else runs into the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26664545/running-lap-request-in-startup-script-linux/26665344#26665344

Comment: @Devin, you are right, it is a perl program/module that I have seen installed on almost any linux server I have met. If it isn't installed, you can surely use your distro package manager to install it (e.g. `libwww-perl` in ubuntu and then you just have to specify the right path to it - e.g. /usr/bin/lwp-request. Sorry, I haven't done this in the answer but /bin/sh requires full paths to operate. I think /bin/bash uses the PATH env variable and it works without full paths too.