# running lap-request in startup script linux

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I have a startup script running on boot in Linx:

**/etc/init/selfconfig**

```
#! /bin/sh  
# /etc/init.d/selfconfig

USER=root
HOME=/root

export USER HOME

/usr/bin/perl /boot/coder_settings/saconfig.pl

exit 0
```

this script runs a perl script

**/boot/coder_settings/saconfig.pl**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

lwp-request -m GET http://192.168.1.16:3000/hostname > /boot/coder_settings/hostname.txt
```

But the I'm getting this error:

`Search pattern not terminated at /boot/coder_settings/saconfig.pl line 3.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try : lwp-request -m GET 'http://192.168.1.16:3000/hostname' > /boot/coder_settings/hostname.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although lwp-request is a perl script, it's setup to run as a command line program.

You can simply change your bash script from;

```
#! /bin/sh 
....
/usr/bin/perl /boot/coder_settings/saconfig.pl
```

To;

```
#! /bin/sh 
....
lwp-request -m GET http://192.168.1.16:3000/hostname > /boot/coder_settings/hostname.txt
```

If you want to run lwp-request as a shell command from perl use backticks change your perl script to;

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

`lwp-request -m GET http://192.168.1.16:3000/hostname > /boot/coder_settings/hostname.txt`
```

Comment: holy moly you're right! i just needed to add backticks wrapping the perl script. thank you!